# how to copy specific line from text files in multiple zip folders?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

i am trying to copy line from text file in zip folder by matching partial string,
zip folders are in a shared folder
is there a way to copy strings from text files and send it to one output text file.
how to do it using python..
is it possible with zip_archive?

i tried using this, with no luck.

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('C:/Users/Analytics Vidhya/Desktop/test.zip') 
# having First.csv zipped file.
df = pd.read_csv(zf.open('First.csv'))
```

Comment: What's the problem your having? Is there an error message?

Comment: I have duplicated what you have shown (opening a ZIP archive and reading a CSV file using `pandas`) and it works _perfectly_, could you please be more explicit with the problems you are facing?  is it a problem with `zipfile`, is it a problem with `pandas` or, as I suspect, is it a problem with accessing and using the file content?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike *@strava* answer, you don't actually have to extract... `zipfile` gives you excellent [API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) for manipulating files. Here is a simple example of reading each file inside a simple zip (I zipped only one `.txt` file):

```
import zipfile
zip_path = r'C:\Users\avi_na\Desktop\a.zip'
niddle = '2'

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path) 
for file_name in zf.namelist():
    print(file_name, zf.read(file_name))
    if(niddle in str(zf.read(file_name))):
        print('found substring!!')
```

output:

```
a.txt b'1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n'
found substring!!
```

Using this example you can easily elaborate and read each one of the files, search the text for your string, and write it to output file.

For more info, check `printdir, read, write, open, close` members of `zipfile.ZipFile`

If you just want to extract and then use `pd.read_csv`, that's also fine:

```
import zipfile
zip_path = r'...\a.zip'
unzip_dir = "unzip_dir"

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path) 
for file_name in zf.namelist():
    if '.csv' in file_name: # make sure file is .csv
        zf.extract(file_name, unzip_dir)
        df = pd.read_csv(open("{}/{}".format(unzip_dir,file_name)))
```

Comment: In the last part of your answer you have written `df = pd.read_csv(zf.open(...` but shouldn't it be a plain `pd.read_csv(open(...` as you have already extracted the file?

Comment: Thanks! `zf` must have slipped in and I overlooked it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try extracting them first, and then treating them as normal csv files

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile( path to zip )
zf.extract('first.csv', path to save directory )
file = open('path\first.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a script that does what *I suppose* you need — please note that we DO NOT need `pandas` if we want to simply match a string against a line's content, it'd be different if you want to match on a specific field, a numerical value etc — hence I am not using `pandas`...

```
$ cat zip.py
from sys import argv
from zipfile import ZipFile
'''
Usage python zip.py string ziparchive1 [ziparchive2 ...]
'''

def interesting(fn):
    # just an example
    return fn[-4:].lower() == '.csv'

script, text, zips = argv

if len(argv) == 3:
    # if 3 arguments, 'zips' is a string and iterating (below) on a
    # string gives us the individual characters in it, not exactly
    # what we want, hence we force it to be a list
    zips = [zips]

# iterate on archives' names    
for arch_name in zips:
    # instance a zipfile object
    archive = ZipFile(arch_name)
    # iterate on the names of contained files
    for file_name in archive.namelist():
        # skip directories
        if file_name[-1] == '/': continue
        if interesting(file_name):
            line_no = 0
            for line in archive.open(file_name):
                line_no += 1
                if text in line:
                    # here I just print the matching line, if you need
                    # something more complex you can use the
                    # 'arch_name', the 'file_name' and the 'line_no'
                    # to pinpoint the position of the matching line
                    print(line)
$
```

Comment: i have tried this with few changes but i am getting error.
    script, text, zips = argv
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Comment: It seems that you may have missed the line _"Usage: python zip.py string ziparchive1 [ziparchive2 ...]"_ that explains how to invoke the script... The script expects at least 3 arguments on the command line. ① by convention, the first argument is the script name ② the string that you want to match ③ the filename of the first ZIP archive to search.  If you want to search more  ZIP archives you just name them on the command line (as exemplified in the _Usage_ line).  Also a wildcard works, as long as it is expanded by the shell, `$ python zip.py 'hole' arch0?.zip`  acts on `archo1.zip`, etc.